# In Outlook pdf file named has no source. i am getting error please try removing this file again how can i solve it

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm writing an Outlook add-in.
In this plugin, I am uploading the attachments with the help of SDK. Sometimes it performs the upload process without any problems, but sometimes the code gives an error. I couldn't understand why the problem is. how can i solve this problem.

```
    {"ClassName":"System.IO.FileLoadException","Message":"Cannot save the attachment.","Data":null,"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment.SaveAsFile(String Path)\r\n   at  OutlookAddIn.BusinessLayer.ThisAddin.ThisAddinMethod.LinkCollection(MailItem MailItemObj) in C:\\Users\\MYPC\\Desktop\\OfficeAddin\\OfficeAddins\\OutlookAddIn\\BusinessLayer\\ThisAddin\\ThisAddinMethod.cs:line 171","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":"8\nSaveAsFile\nOutlookAddIn, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null\nMicrosoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment\nVoid SaveAsFile(System.String)","HResult":-2147024864,"Source":"Microsoft Outlook","WatsonBuckets":null,"FileLoad_FileName":null,"FileLoad_FusionLog":null}
```

[image]

```
    foreach (Attachment attach in MailItemObj.Attachments)
            {
                i = i + 1;
                string get = attach.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E");
                if (!html.Contains("cid:" + attach.DisplayName) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(get) || !html.Contains("cid:" + get)))
                {
                    var name = attach.DisplayName;
                    try
                    {
                        var index = attachmentInfoList.FirstOrDefault(f=>f.Id==attach.Index);

                        string filePath = Path.Combine(tempPath, attach.DisplayName);
                        string mainDirectoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
                        string extension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
                        string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
                        var number = oldFileList.Count(y => y == name);
                        string customFilePath = string.Empty;
                        string newFileName = string.Empty;
                        string fullFileName = string.Empty;
                        if (index!=null)
                        {
                            if (index.NewFileName!=null)
                            {

                         
                            
                            customFilePath = Path.Combine(mainDirectoryPath, index.NewFileName);
                            fullFileName = Path.GetFileName(customFilePath);
                            
                             newFileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(customFilePath);
                             fullFileName = Path.GetFileName(customFilePath);
                            attach.SaveAsFile(customFilePath);
                            linkFileCollection.Add(new SDK.V2.OutlookDTO.LinkFile(ExtensionTask.GetStreamFromUrl(customFilePath), fullFileName) { Path = customFilePath });
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                           
                            customFilePath = Path.Combine(mainDirectoryPath, fullFileName);
                            fullFileName = Path.GetFileName(customFilePath);
                      
                             newFileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(customFilePath);
                            //string fullFileName = Path.GetFileName(customFilePath);
                            attach.SaveAsFile(customFilePath);
                            linkFileCollection.Add(new SDK.V2.OutlookDTO.LinkFile(ExtensionTask.GetStreamFromUrl(customFilePath), fullFileName) { Path = customFilePath });

                        }



                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex)
                    {
                        BusinessLayer.Logger.LogWriter.WriteLog(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex));
                        throw new System.InvalidOperationException("FileAttach: " + name + " " + lang.FileAttachError);
                    }
                }

            }
```

I have an error log that crashes at the top

Comment: Are you running Outlook in the online Exchange mode?

Comment: What are the exact values passed to the `SaveAsFile` method?

Comment: I am sending string path to SaveAsFile method. I work in online exchange

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are running out of RPC channels. Avoid using multiple dot notation (especially in a loop) and release all object as soon as you are done with them. Use the for loop instead:

```
Attachments attachments = inMailItem.Attachments;
for (int myCount = 1; myCount <= attachments.Count; myCount++)
{
  Attachment attach = attachments.Item(myCount);
  attach.SaveAsFile(attachmentFilePath);

  // release the attachment COM object after
  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(attach);
  attach = null;
}
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(attachments);
```

You can see such kind of problems if you are using Exchange store in the online mode. Exchange server tracks the number of RPC channels used by each client on the per-object level.

Comment: I can't access the item method here attachments.Item(). Attachment attach = attachments[myCount]; i do it this way but i still get the same error